# HTML5 video controls - Cannot play after pause in chrome only

Tags: html, google-chrome, video

Hiya I was hoping for some help if possible please. I have an HTML5 video that is acting strange when viewed in chrome.

When the user hits play for the first time, the video plays.
If they click pause the video pauses. But then the play button doesn't work at all and the only way to make the video play is to click the video screen.

Any ideas on why this is happening and how i can fix this issue please?

Here's the code I'm using:

```
<video width="560" height="320" preload controls>
<source src="videos/Testimonial2.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
<source src="videos/Testimonial2.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
<source src="videos/Testimonial2.webm" "type=video/webm" />
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.1.swf" width="560" height="320">
<param name="movie" value="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.1.swf" />
<param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
<param name="bgcolor" value="#FFFFFF" />
<param name="quality" value="high" />
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />
<a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflash">
<img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" />
</a>
<param name="flashvars" value="vdo=videos/Testimonial2.flv&amp;autoplay=false" />
<!--[if !IE]>-->
</object>
<!--<![endif]-->
</object>
</video>
```

Thank You :)

Comment: Hi, why do you use two closing </object> tags instead of one?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately for me, Slashin8r's answer didn't help me, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16566828/chrome-no-longer-supports-html5-video?rq=1) did. Basically, I just had to rearrange my sources so that the OGV and WEBM videos came before the MP4. Don't know why. I left preload="none" on, too. Seems silly, but hey, whatever works, right?

BEFORE:

```
<video width="1920" height="1080" controls preload="none">
    <source src="example.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    <source src="example.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
    <source src="example.webm" type="video/webm" />
</video>
```

AFTER:

```
<video width="1920" height="1080" controls preload="none">
    <source src="example.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
    <source src="example.webm" type="video/webm" />
    <source src="example.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

Comment: Or WEBM. Turned out that the OGG file was waaaay too grainy on desktop, so I switched those two around and it looked much better and still worked.