# Chrome No Longer Supports HTML5 Video?

Tags: html, google-chrome, video

I have a website I was working on for a uni project, and I embedded a video using the HTML5 video tag. The code looks like this:

```
<video width="400" controls="">
<source src="images/Nexus.mp4" type="video/mp4">
Something broke :/
</video>
```

And it was working fine at uni, but when I went home it no longer worked. I did a bit of research, and Chrome doesn't support mp4. Ok fine, so I found a site that allowed me to convert to the other supported types so now my code looks like this:

```
<video width="400" controls="">
<source src="images/Nexus.mp4" type="video/mp4">
<source src="images/Nexus.ogv" type="video/ogg">
<source src="images/Nexus.webm" type="video/webm">
Something broke :/
</video>
```

And both the ogg and webm were working (I tested each one individually using comments). But at home it still didn't work. It comes up with the video widget thing and displays the correct length of video but the play button is disabled and there is no still image. But it still worked at uni. Until today. Now I have the same problem. Have Chrome stopped supporting the HTML5 video tag?

*NOTE* the ogg and webm still work on firefox, but not mp4

Comment: "And it was working fine at uni, but when I went home it no longer worked" <- what does this mean?  Which of the files are "at uni" and which are "at home"?  Is the web server in both places or one place?  Is it two different client PCs or a laptop you've transported between the two places?  In short, if the environment has changed and produced different behaviour, start by describing in detail how the environment has changed.

Comment: I have the files on my portable hard drive. All that changed was the computer I was viewing them off. Same version of Chrome.

Comment: "All that changed", just the whole operating system?  So are these files coming from the filesystem with `file:///` urls or are you using a web server?

Comment: The site is on my portable hard drive, which is what I was running it off, no web or local servers. The computer and laptop had the same OS and same version of chrome, just different machines

Comment: An OS is a massively complex bit of software likely taking up several gigs of HDD space, are you sure what's on both machines is 'the same'?  Check the MIME types that Chrome is reporting in the network tab, if they're not what you're expecting (eg. `video\mp4` then look for 'file types' or 'open with' settings in whatever your file management software happens to be.

Comment: Apparently on latest Chrome Dev 43.0.2357.93  it does not support .ogv neither :( (source: html5test)

Answer (score 1):

try to rearrange it so that

```
<video width="400" controls>
<source src="images/Nexus.ogv" type="video/ogg">
<source src="images/Nexus.webm" type="video/webm">
<source src="images/Nexus.mp4" type="video/mp4">
Something broke :/
</video>
```

and remove the empty value for attribute controls