# Does server get overloaded and thus stops playing video 'sometimes'?

Tags: java, html, ajax, web-services

There is a 90 minute clip on the server, that gets played while all other server operations are performed. Sometimes while in the process of pausing and playing, video hangs and doesn't play. If we forward or move the video progress bar back, nothing happens.

Currently, the video plays like :

```
<video id="match" width="530" controls>
                       <source src='etsk1.mp4' type="video/mp4">
                        Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

Do I need to do this, some other way? Does the server overload and is unable to handle the video?

*Note:The application is running on my localhost.*

Comment: Could it be a browser issue? Have you tried in multiple browsers?

Comment: @enigma I have used only chrome. Should that be a browser issue?

Comment: Try setting `preload="none"` as per this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16464123/html5-video-controls-cannot-play-after-pause-in-chrome-only ?

Comment: @enigma I am not sure if not pre loading the video will help?

Comment: What does your browser console say? Does the network tab give any clues as to the state of the streaming?