# Why there is Error in Playing or Pausing When Hovered in React

Tags: html, reactjs, react-hooks, html5-video

I have several videos to show in my app.
I wanted it that if it is hovered it would play and when the mouse leaves it, it would pause. However my problem is that its outputting an error `Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The play() request was interrupted by a call to pause()`.

Here's my code below

```
const Video = ({ video }) => {
  const videoRef = useRef();
  return (
    <div
      onMouseOver={() => video?.promoVideoUrl && videoRef?.current?.play()}
      onFocus={() => video?.promoVideoUrl && videoRef?.current?.play()}
      onMouseOut={() => video?.promoVideoUrl && videoRef?.current?.pause()}
      onBlur={() => video?.promoVideoUrl && videoRef?.current?.pause()}
      className="col-12"
    >
      <>
        <a target="_blank" href={`/videos/${video.id}`} rel="noreferrer">
          <video
            ref={videoRef}
            muted
            height="100%"
            width="100%"
            poster={video?.poster}
            src={video?.url}
            loop
            preload="auto"
          />
        </a>
      </>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Video;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you play the video, it needs to load the video first, and then actually play it. If you pause while doing this, you'll get the error.

The solution is to use the promise returned by the `play` action, and wait for it to resolve in order to pause. See this [article](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/06/play-request-was-interrupted).

```js
const { useRef, useMemo } = React;

const useVideo = (url) => {
  const videoRef = useRef();
  
  const handlers = useMemo(() => {  
    let videoLoaded;
    return {
      start() {
        if(!url || !videoRef.current) return;
      
        videoLoaded = videoRef.current.play()
      },
      pause() {
        if(!url || !videoRef.current) return;
      
        videoLoaded.then(() => {
          videoRef.current.pause();
        });
      }
    }
  }, [url]);

  return {
    videoRef,
    ...handlers
  };
};

const Video = ({ video }) => {
  const { start, pause, videoRef } = useVideo(video.url);
  return (
    <div
      onMouseOver={start}
      onMouseOut={pause}
      onFocus={start}
      onBlur={pause}
      className="col-12"
    >
      <a target="_blank" href={`/videos/${video.id}`} rel="noreferrer">
        <video
          ref={videoRef}
          muted
          height="100%"
          width="100%"
          poster={video.poster}
          src={video.url}
          loop
          preload="auto"
        />
      </a>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Video video={{ url: 'http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ForBiggerBlazes.mp4', id: '' }} />,
  root
)
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you. However there are videos in my API that `url` is null. and the error appears like `Cannot read property 'then' of undefined` in   pause(). How can we prevent that? Thank you.

Comment: The stackoverflow snippet doesn't support conditional chaining. Change `videoLoaded.current.then` to `videoLoaded.current?.then` in your code, or use the blocking condition I've added to pause.

Comment: Hi Ori. this causes freeze in browser when there is many videos. I think its because its still playing in the background after taking pause? I think we can do set the currentTime to 0? is that a good thing?

Comment: Not related to your problem - I've updated to solution to work without the ref.

Comment: See if this answer helps you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16464123/html5-video-controls-cannot-play-after-pause-in-chrome-only

Comment: It does play but after several times of filtering videos, it freezes. It might be due to this

Comment: Any idea of that? Maybe you have to stop the video from loading? cause when you click pause, it still is loading/playing video from background

Comment: Have you checked this link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16464123/html5-video-controls-cannot-play-after-pause-in-chrome-only ?

Comment: hmm seems working. just change preload to none.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen for two reasons. Similar questions are already answerend in stackoverflow.com

**Reason one - calling pause without waiting for play promise to resolve**

**Reason two - calling play when the tab is not focused**

The solution is sa below:

```
const = videoRef.current;

// Initializing values

    letisPlaying = true;
    
    // On video playing toggle values
    video.onplaying = function() {
        isPlaying = true;
    };
    
    // On video pause toggle values
    video.onpause = function() {
        isPlaying = false;
    };
    
    // Play video function
    function playVid() {      
        if (video.paused && !isPlaying) {
            video.play();
        }
    } 
    
    // Pause video function
    function pauseVid() {     
        if (!video.paused && isPlaying) {
            video.pause();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Pls complete your answer